# Return list of date between specific range selected from datepicker (include and exclude weekends)

Tags: javascript

I try to code with JavaScript and now, I have another problem. The intended goal is to calculate the number of days and to return list of those date between two selected dates from datepicker. The trick is: the system should provide two option: during all day of the week (including Saturday and Sunday) and only during working days. I tried to do this on my own, but I am stuck. I have also tried to find out if anyone happened to asked the same question, but the result is no. Here is my code. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

```js
$("#calculate").click(function() {

  // TO CALCULATE TOTAL DAYS

  startdate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);
  enddate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  var days = Math.ceil(enddate - startdate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
  days = days - (weeks * 2);

  var month = startdate.getMonth();
  var day = startdate.getDate();
  var year = startdate.getFullYear();


  // ONLY DURING WORKING DAYS

  $("#weekday").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

      var startday = startdate.getDay();
      var endday = enddate.getDay();

      if (startday - endday > 1) {
        days = days - 2
      }

      if (startday == 0 && endday != 6) {
        days = days - 1
      }

      if (endday == 6 && startday != 0) {
        days = days - 1
      }

      // TO SHOW THE LIST OF DATE BETWEEN START AND END DATE

      while (startdate <= enddate) {
        if (startday < 6 && startday > 0) {
          month = startdate.getMonth() + 1
        }
        if (month <= 9) {
          month = "0" + month
        }
        var day = startdate.getdate();
        if (day <= 9) {
          day = "0" + day
        }

      }
      
      startdate.setDate(startdate.getDate() + 1);

    }
  })


})

var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
var delivery = Math.round(quantity / days);
var datearray = document.write(day + "." + month + "." + startdate.getFullYear());


if (enddate < startdate) {
  alert("Start date must be earlier than end date!")
} else if (quantity == 0) {
  alert("Quantity must be bigger than 0")
} else {
  append("<br>Total " + days + " selected days<br/>");
  append("<br>Shipment" + delivery + " pc(s) per day<br/>");
  append("<br>During period of" + datearray + "<br/>")
}


});
```

Comment: You are assigning a `while` loop to a variable ? This is not allowed. Can you double check that your code is how you want it to be ?

Comment: Ok. I have tried other way as well (edited now in the snippet) , but it didnt work either.